# Executing a Python Script when Web Page is loaded

Tags: javascript, python, html, web

I'm trying to have it so that when my web page is loaded, a python script is executed. The website is run on an apache server and the script is in the same directory as the index.html (it's a very small project).

Is there anyway I can do this? I'm not trying to output the data from the python file to the webpage, nor am I trying to affect anything client-side, I simply want the python script to execute and do it's thing whenever the web page is loaded.

Is there some sort of javascript function that I can use? I've searched around but really haven't found anything similar. Thanks!

Comment: why not set up your script as `index.py` and have it output the HTML and then do whatever it is you want it to do?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I quite understand your explanation, but I need it so that when index.html is loaded(a webpage of it's own), that this script will run. Unless....are you suggesting that I can have the index file be a python script, and that if a user put that in as the address that it would pull up a page of whatever the python script was executing? (the python script does actually create a webpage, it just doesn't launch it to the user, is that possible?)

Sorry I'm kind of a noob at this stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, your web server is already set up to run Python scripts. Presumably it will recognize an `index.py` file as any other `index.(html|cgi|pl|etc.)` document. Create the following as `index.py` in your DocumentRoot:

```
my_webpage = """
Content Type: text/html\n\n

<html>
<head>
<title>Python-generated text!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>I just made an HTML page with Python!</h1>
</body>
</html>
"""
print(my_webpage)
# now that that's out of the way, let's run our script
import stuff

def myfunc():
    # awesomeness goes here...
```

and make sure it's executable. Now, whenever a user requests `http://www.yourserver.com/` the server will run `index.py`, which prints out the HTML content, including the headers, then goes on to run the rest of your script.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input, this is exactly the kind of thing I need, however I'm really quite lost when it comes to configuring this apache server(it's running on redhat linux which I have no prior experiance with) do you know of a good guide I could look up for this?

Comment: @user2395417 - just google setting up apache and mod_wsgi. It's likely already set up and ready to go, you might just need to activate the module. There are great docs on the apache website, and if you get stuck at a particular spot you can of course always ask on [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this too. I had a python script(which gets me data from another website) which gets executed when you click on a button.
I used Ruby on Rails for my client side code. I embedded the script file in my ruby controller which then gets called by my form and hence it gets executed.

eg: 
cmd = " python getData.py "
exec( cmd )

Comment: I've never used Ruby on Rails before, would it take me long to be able to learn enough of it to simply know how to execute that one piece of code?